# Error generating android resource from XML string

Tags: android

I'm trying to edit an XML layout, change a color, and create a new drawable from the XML. I get the following error, which has no useful results on google: "android.util.XmlPullAttributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser". The error is occurring inside of "Drawable.createFromXml", which indicates that the XML parsed correctly and was of correct type. I verified correct loading of the XML text file.

The ultimate goal is to change the progress bar color programmatically to any possible color.

I removed the em

```
try{
            String xml_string = this.readRawTextFile("progress_bar_xml.xml");
            xml_string = xml_string.replace("#95d233", "#FF0000");
            InputStream xmlIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml_string.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(xmlIS, null); // // XmlResourceParser
            Drawable progressDrawable = Drawable.createFromXml(res, xpp);
            holder.lessoncompletedPB.setProgressDrawable(progressDrawable);
            progressDrawable = null;
            xpp = null;
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String err = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            err = err+";";
        }
```

Current XML File contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape>
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#95d233"
        android:endColor="#95d233"
    />
</shape>
```

Full source XML layout (not used and also fails):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#95d233"
                android:endColor="#95d233"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: I suggest you read some android tutorials and figure out how to inflate a view from xml. You are making this much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: can't do that. xml resources files are compiled in a binary format. You can't modify them at runtime.

Comment: generating shape drawable at runtime is done using for example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

Comment: I now understand why Samsung has life insurance. You will perish trying to manipulate XML like that...

Comment: Thanks for all the insults. I won't answer each one. There is no problem getting and manipulating the XML and it is as expected. The failure is in Drawable.createFromXml(). For now, I have solved the issue with 2 progress bars. On iOS I rendered the image with SVG, but I couldn't get that to work here either.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate goal is to change the progress bar color programmatically to any possible color.

You can do this using only this line of code.

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.rgb(0xFF, 0, 0), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: This would require that I used an indeterminate progress bar. The result is a completely different bar that animates (or in the other case does nothing when not changed to indeterminate).